# link_to syntax? want to hyperlink (variable.id + "string") together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, concatenation, link-to

```
link_to feed_item.votes_for + "Into it!", into_it_micropost_path(feed_item.id)
```

I basically want the hyperlink to be that variable next to the string "Into it!"

how can i achieve this? thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually it seems to me your version is supposed to work just fine.

Maybe try to put it in another way:

```
link_to "#{feed_item.votes_for} Into it!", into_it_micropost_path(feed_item.id)
```

Don't forget that for the link to appear you will have to put it inside `<%= %>`

Comment: my version results in the error: string can't be coerced into fixnum. this worked perfectly thanks. assume its because the variable returns a number so it thinks im adding. maybe have to to.s the variable but this is much simpler

Comment: Glad I could help. A little advice for next time - also put the specific error you're getting in your question - will will lead for faster and more accurate answers for you.

Comment: note the double quotes , it'll not work inside the single quote